# is it possible to operate two service in the one stripe account?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have one c corp corporation and run two services.
Each service has a different domain. However,
in stripe, one domain is registered in one account.

In general, how does stripe operate each service with multiple domains in one legal entity?

Comment: c crop is created by stripe atlas

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned on the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/multiple-accounts): "You must use separate Stripe accounts for projects, websites, or businesses that operate independently from one another."